# Unable to run azcopy tool with c#

Tags: c#, cmd, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have written a console application to call the AZcopy tool programmatically, but I was not able to call azcopy tool. Can you please redirect me the workable source ? I have downloaded azcopy_windows_amd64_10.12.1 and put azcopy.exe into C:\Windows\System32\azcopy.exe location

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strCmdText = @"AzCopy.exe sync ""D:\temp"" ""https://myhubforazcopy.blob.core.windows.net/myhubforazcopy1?sp=racwdl&st=2021-09-05T17:19:11Z&se=2021-09-06T01:19:11Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=MAraJ0PxqJMDdYuWzrOUEwYda%2BkXEukP%2Fs%3D"" --destination-delete=true";
       
        CallProcess(strCmdText);
    }

public static void CallProcess(string strCmdText)
    {
       
        //C:\Windows\System32\azcopy.exe
        var process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            Arguments = strCmdText,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            WorkingDirectory = @"D:\AzCopy\bin\Debug\"
        };


        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.Start();

        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Comment: Why are you starting a shell, only to then run AzCopy?  Why not just start Azcopy?

Comment: I want to execute mentioned command programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting `cmd` with the program you want to execute as the argument doesn't actually runt that program, you'll need to pass the entire argument (your program) after the `/c` flag, like so:

```
string strCmdText = @"/c AzCopy.exe sync ""D:\temp"" ...
```

Make sure that `AzCopy` is in your `PATH` or specify the precise path to it

But it would be better if you just directly run `AzCopy` instead of starting a command prompt which then starts AzCopy, this would be done like so:

```
// Notice how the 'azcopy' at the start is gone
var arguments = @"""D:\temp"" ""https://myhubforazcopy.blob ..."

var process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\azcopy.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    Arguments = arguments,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    WorkingDirectory = @"D:\AzCopy\bin\Debug\"
};
```

Comment: Now it's complaining about at process.Start(); The system cannot find the file specified.  What do you mean by "Make sure that AzCopy is in your PATH or specify the precise path to it" ?

Comment: You can only start a program (a process) if the environment knows where it is, to know where it is the system looks in the Environment variable called `PATH` you can read more of it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), you can edit them as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them). If you don't want to edit your path variable then you can simply specify the exact path as the filename, so instead of just `azcopy` use `C:\Windows\System32\azcopy.exe`

Comment: Thank you for your help, Now i am able to run azcopy utility very well. But there is still one question that if I would change my source folder would it be any problem that people used to get here https://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2017/10/running-multiple-copies-of-azcopy.html

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strCmdText = @"/c azcopy.exe sync ""D:\temp"" ""https://myhubforazcopy.blob.core.windows.net/myhubforazcopy1?sp=racwdl&st=2021-09-05T17:19:11Z&se=2021-09-06T01:19:11Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=MAraJ0PxqJMDdYuWzrOUEwYda%2BkXEukP%2Fs%3D"" --delete-destination=true";
        
        CallProcess(strCmdText);
    }

 public static void CallProcess(string strCmdText)
    {
        var process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            Arguments = strCmdText,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
        };


        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.Start();

        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

[image]